# What is the difference between calling a script from the shell and using system()?

Tags: c++, linux, process, parent-child

I have built a bash script to start up some processes in my system. It simply calls the process and associated config file. Same as I would call from the command line.

```
#!/bin/bash
# Start specified process in a new session
setsid $1 &>/dev/null &
```

So to start up `someprocess`, I would call from the command line:

```
root@supercomputer:~# start someprocess
```

This works like a charm. Every process, every time. But when I make a `system` call from a different running C++ process, `someprocess` never starts up.

```
system( "start someprocess" )
```

This approach for 90% of my processes, except for one. The only difference in the working and not working processes is that the non-working one uses proprietary libraries underneath. I recently added the `setsid` option to the bash script in hopes that starting a new session would help, but it made no difference. I've also tried `popen`,  and `execv`. No change.

So my question is what is the difference between calling something with `system()` and just making that same call from the command line?

All processes are written in C++ on Linux.

Comment: What's different: Maybe the environment?

Comment: Have you check the usual suspects - permissions, LD_PATH, environment vars, etc?  The C++ system wrapper is the same user and/or root, etc?  What kind of errno values are you getting back from system, popen, execv, etc?

Comment: @Kerrek SB, @Duck There are environment variables set in `~/.bashrc` for this program, how do I make sure/check that they get set when I start my program with `system()`? I assumed that calling a bash script meant that `bashrc` got sourced

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`.bashrc` is only invoked if bash is run as interactive, non-login shell. If it's invoked as non-interactive shell, as when using `system()` on a script with a bash shebang, it only reads the configuration file pointed to by `$BASH_ENV`.

That means you have the following options:

- add `-l` to the shebang - causes the shell to read `~/.profile` at startup
- set `$BASH_ENV` to the script you want sourced before calling `system()`
- add `-i` to the shebang - invokes bash as interactive shell and causes it to read `~/.bashrc`, but will also effect how bash handles input/output.

I'd recommend the first option.

You can find a detailed explanation of how bash reads it's startup files [here](http://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bashref.html#Bash-Startup-Files). I'm not sure this will solve your problem completely, but it may at leas shed some light on that part of the issue.

Comment: The first two solutions didn't seem to work, but I was able to include a source command in my shell scripts that set all pertinent environment variables. You put me on the right path. Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

Check the environment variables that are used in the system() call. For example, call system to print out some of the variables, and see if they match what you see from the command line.

Likely they are not being sourced correctly.